# How to sum up a list of float in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to sum up a list of values from my data and label it when it has reaches the condition set using python, like this table shown bellow.

[image]

Example: I have this **Data**, using cumulative sum i have this **CumSum**,
but 
if **CumSum** = > 5, then the **Label** is **X** and it will start counting again 
if **CumSum** < = -5, then its **Y** and will start adding again 
else the **Label** is **A** and will continue to count until it reach the condition set.

How do I code it using python?

I had tried the suggested answers but i cant figure it out. I hope I had rephrase the question clearly.

Thanks

Comment: You need to use a while loop to adress this `sum` until a condition is met.

Comment: Why did you add the tags `pandas` or `numpy`?

Comment: Removed the pandas tag. This problem is also not suited for numpy since the cumulative sum within each interval could have any shape

Comment: The None case does not seem to be specified in the question to me. Can you please shed light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function that will produce a generator that will return x and y labels every time the condition is met.

```
my_list = [2, 3, -3, -2, 4, -4, -1, -2, -5, -6, 7, 2, 4]

def custom_counter(my_list):
    sum = 0
    for num in my_list:
        sum += num
        if not -5 < sum < 5:
            yield "x" if sum > 0 else "y"
            sum = 0

print(list(custom_counter(my_list)))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['x', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'x', 'x']
```

**UPDATE since you totally changed the context and output expectation of the question**

Having had several answers to your question you then changed the scope of the question and asked for something different. This should have been raised as a new question however as you have already updated your question i have updated my answer to reflect your updated question.

```
import pandas as pd

def custom_counter(my_list):
    total = 0
    label = "A"
    for num in my_list:
        total += num
        if not -5 < total < 5:
            label = "X" if total > 0 else "Y"
            yield [num, total, label]
            total = 0
            label = "A"
        else:
            yield [num, total, label]

my_list = [3.0, 2.5, -4.1, 1.2, -3.8, 2.9, -1.0, 3.4, 3.6, 2.7]
df = pd.DataFrame(custom_counter(my_list), columns=['Data','CumSum','Label'])
print(df)
```

**output**

```
   Data  CumSum Label
0   3.0     3.0     A
1   2.5     5.5     X
2  -4.1    -4.1     A
3   1.2    -2.9     A
4  -3.8    -6.7     Y
5   2.9     2.9     A
6  -1.0     1.9     A
7   3.4     5.3     X
8   3.6     3.6     A
9   2.7     6.3     X
```

Comment: I got an error when i tried your code
`TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'builtin_function_or_method'`

Comment: Code works fine for me in both 2.7 and 3.6. What version of python are you running.  it seems in your code it thinks sum is a built in method. Can you try chaning the variable name `sum` to something else like `total`

Comment: I use other variable since `sum` is a built in function before running it. I use python 3.7.

Comment: How to generate with 3 labelled output? as shown in the table i provided? You have only **X** and **Y**. Thanks

Comment: its bad practice to change a question when others have already provided answers. You should ask a new question as this totally changes the requirement of your original question

Comment: As you have already changed the question i have updated my answer to reflect your new requirement

Comment: I apologize, I rephrased the question and add some additional info and data to state the problem clearly, because it was hold. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple and clean approach using a generator function:

```
def binsum(l):
    out = 0
    for i in l:
        out += i
        if abs(out) >= 5:
            yield out
            out = 0
```

---

```
l = [4, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1, 4, 1]

list(binsum(l))
# [5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5]
```

---

Quick check adding the cumulative sum within each interval:

```
[4, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1, 4, 1]
 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 6, 0, 1, 3, 6, 2, 6, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very simple approach using `abs` and a for loop: I added comments to help follow code

```
data  = [1.7, -0.2, 1.5, 2.3, 1.8, -4.5, 1.6, -3.9]
s, idx = 0, 0 # s will hold the running sum, idx will hold the starting index for each iteration

for i, num in enumerate(data):
  s += num # adding to the sum
  if abs(s) >= 5: #checking if sum is >= 5 or <= -5
    print((idx, i), s) # prints the range the sum was found and the sum
    s, idx = 0, i + 1 # resets the index and sum
```

This prints:

```
(0, 3) 5.3
(4, 7) -5.0
```

Instead of using `x` and `y` I'd suggest using a list and accessing by index. This can be done using the above approach by appending to a list instead of printing.

```
data  = [1.7, -0.2, 1.5, 2.3, 1.8, -4.5, 1.6, -3.9]
s, sums = 0, []

for num in data:
  s += num
  if abs(s) >= 5:
    sums.append(s)
    s = 0
```

This makes a list:

```
[5.3, -5.0]
```

Of course you can include the indexes or even the values using the enumerate approach in the original code block but this I assume is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

data  = [1.7, -0.2, 1.5, 2.3, 1.8, -4.5, 1.6, -3.9]
resultA = 'X'
resultB = 'Y'
cumdata = np.cumsum(data)
result = []
i = -1
while len(cumdata)>0:
    if np.sum((cumdata >= 5) + (cumdata <= -5)) > 0:
        i = np.where((cumdata >= 5) + (cumdata <= -5))[0][0]
        if cumdata[i] >= 5:
            result.append(resultA)
        else:
            result.append(resultB)
    #else:
    #    result.append(None) # in case you would like to have a None in the end if the conditions are no more met towards the end.
    cumdata = cumdata[i + 1:] - cumdata[i]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
['X', 'Y']
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't got time to test it (i wrote it on my phone, might have error syntax) but is it the idea of your program ?

```
def function(array):

    n = len(array)
    sum = 0
    index = 0
    for i in range(n):
        if sum > 5:
            print(array[index:i], X)
            sum = 0
            index = i
        elsif sum < -5:
            print(array[index:i], Y)
            sum = 0
            index = i
        else:
          sum += array[i]
   return "end of program"
```

Comment: I understand it's from phone, but the `sum` variable does not seem to update in any way.

Answer (score 0):

```
vals = [1.7, -0.2, 1.5, 2.3, 1.8, -4.5, 1.6, -3.9]

master_lst = []
lst = []
sum_ = 0
for _ in vals:
    lst.append(_)
    sum_ += _
    if abs(sum_) >= 5:
        sum_ = 0
        master_lst.append(lst)
        lst = []
```

The variable `master_lst` stores the answer:

```
[[1.7, -0.2, 1.5, 2.3], [1.8, -4.5, 1.6, -3.9]]
```

To get the sums, simply:

```
[*map(sum, master_lst)]
```

(the `[*...]` syntax is equivalent to calling `list(...)`)

Which gives:

```
[5.3, -5.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rather complicated but fun approach to your problem using the itertools module and recursion. There are some tricky complications to your question as posed in involving float arithmetic and the need to account for negative numbers in the list (it's much easier with a list of positive integers.)

```
import itertools as it
index = -1      #for tracking indexes

def accumulator(mylist, triggers, labels):
    global index    #allows recursive calls to get right index (like 'static')
    index += 1
    print(f"{mylist}, {index}") #reporter
    a = it.accumulate(mylist)   #itertools generator function
    if len(mylist) == 0:        #base case
        print('EMPTY LIST')
        return
    count = 0
    while count < len(mylist):
        print(f"element={mylist[count]:4}, count={count:4}", end=' ')
        count += 1
        temp = next(a)
        print(f"sum={temp}")
        #use a tolerance range when dealing with floats
        if temp < (triggers[index] + .001) and temp > (triggers[index] - .001):
            print(labels[index])
            truncated = mylist[count:]     #creates shortened list
            accumulator(truncated, triggers, labels)    #recursive call
            return                         #jumps out of call stack, critical
    print('\nlist end reached without trigger') #other base case
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    items = [1.7, -0.1, 1.5, 2.3, 1.8, -4.5, 1.6, -3.9]
    triggers = [5.4, -5, 1000]  #add large value to end to avoid out-of-bounds
    labels = ['X','Y']
    accumulator(items, triggers, labels)
```

Sample output works for this specific case:

```
[1.7, -0.2, 1.5, 2.3, 1.8, -4.5, 1.6, -3.9], 0
element= 1.7, count=   0 sum=1.7
element=-0.2, count=   1 sum=1.5
element= 1.5, count=   2 sum=3.0
element= 2.3, count=   3 sum=5.3
X
[1.8, -4.5, 1.6, -3.9], 1
element= 1.8, count=   0 sum=1.8
element=-4.5, count=   1 sum=-2.7
element= 1.6, count=   2 sum=-1.1
element=-3.9, count=   3 sum=-5.0
Y
[], 2
EMPTY LIST
```

However, and this illustrates the problem with decimal floats in the binary world, let's say you change the 0.2 in the list to 0.1 - this is why we need the tolerance range in the conditional test (target changed to 5.4):

```
[1.7, -0.1, 1.5, 2.3, 1.8, -4.5, 1.6, -3.9], 0
element= 1.7, count=   0 sum=1.7
element=-0.1, count=   1 sum=1.5999999999999999
element= 1.5, count=   2 sum=3.0999999999999996
element= 2.3, count=   3 sum=5.3999999999999995
X
[1.8, -4.5, 1.6, -3.9], 1
element= 1.8, count=   0 sum=1.8
element=-4.5, count=   1 sum=-2.7
element= 1.6, count=   2 sum=-1.1
element=-3.9, count=   3 sum=-5.0
Y
[], 2
EMPTY LIST
```

Notice also that the requirement to get the negatives as well makes it much trickier to use a > or < conditional.